# Add filter/search to dropdown menu dynamically filled from a local json file

Tags: javascript, forms, filter, html-select, html-datalist

I'm looking for a way to add filter/search to a dropdown menu that is dynamically filled from a local json file.

Here's my script :

```js
var json = [{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Ann"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Karl"
  },
  {
    "id": 31,
    "name": "Jess"
  }
]

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (i in json) {
    $("#name-selector").append('<option id= "name-data" name="submit" type="submit" value="' + json[i]["name"] + '">' + json[i]["name"] + '</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-selectors">
  <h5>Name</h5>
  <form>
    <select value="false" name="name" id="name-selector" class="selectors">
      <option value="">Select option</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

I've tried to put add an input option in the dropdown menu put it places the input outside the dropdown menu.

Any idea how I could implement this ?

Comment: What is the `type="submit"` attribute/value within every appended `options` element good for?

Answer (score 1):

One gets such search/filter behavior for free, if one utilizes an input control's [`list`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#list) attribute which points to the to be used/applied [`datalist` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) ...

```js
function retrieveAndApplyNameOptions() {

  const $datalist = $('datalist#name-options');
  const $selector = $('select#name-selector');

  // - e.g. retrieved from local storage like ...
  //   ... localStorage.getItem('name-options') 
  const jsonValue =
    '[{"id":3,"name":"Ann"},{"id":4,"name":"Karl"},{"id":31,"name":"Jess"}]';

  const nameOptions = JSON.parse(jsonValue);

  nameOptions.forEach(optionItem => {
    const { name } = optionItem;

    $datalist.append(`<option value="${ name }"></option>`);
    $selector.append(`<option value="${ name }">${ name }</option>`);
  });
}

$(document).ready(retrieveAndApplyNameOptions);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
fieldset { margin: 10px 0; }
```

```html
<datalist id="name-options"></datalist>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Name via datalist options</legend>

    <label>
      <span data-label>Search for a name ...</span>
      <input name="name" list="name-options">
    </label>
  
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Name via select and options</legend>

    <label>
      <span data-label>Choose a name ...</span>
      <select name="name" id="name-selector"></select>
    </label>
  
  </fieldset>
<form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks ! This could be a solution, but I was looking for to add the search bar to the dropdown :)

Comment: @DouxDoux ... what does _" I was looking for to add the search bar to the dropdown"_ actually mean? Your question is tagged `javascript`, `html` and `json`, thus everything is related to behavior and its implementation. In case you're looking for graphic appearance you need to be very specific about what things should look like. And since the latter is not at all connected to behavior this should be a layout/css specific question on its own?

Comment: thx for you help ! i ended up using  `select2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not store the JSON file locally on the client.  The JSON file should live on the server.  It looks like you are using jQuery so I would use AJAX to write the JSON file to the server or read from the server.

Here is an example that will read the JSON file via a PHP script that you have to write.  Research AJAX examples.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "get_json_options.php",
  type: 'post',
  data: '',
  dataType: "json",
  async: true,
  //contentType: false,
  //cache: false,
  //processData: false,
  beforeSend: function() {
    //alert("before");
  },
  success: function(options) {
    console.log(options);
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log("Error in get_json_options.php:" + xhr.responseText);
  }
}); //ajax
```

Comment: Regarding ... _"You can not store the JSON file locally on the client."_ ... how about on that behalf [`localStorage.setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#examples) and  [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) as well as `localStorage.getItem` and  [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for the other way around?